# Virtualization with UEFI'secure boot feature

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, uefi, secure-boot

I'm interested in the notion of emulating digital signature checks in virtual machines—the host can be booted without hardware-based digital signature checks, which can be moved to the VM, and the virtualization can prevent the software-based chain-of-trust from being undercut by the operating system running in the VM. VirtualBox and VMware both support a UEFI environment, and TianoCore is often used as the virtual firmware in such systems, so I'm wondering if any virtualization programs support secure boot. Do such ones exist? Can they be configured to use my own public key(s)?

Comment: You can use Tiano Core OVMF on QEMU to simulate and explore UEFI with secure boot. It will allow you to boot into firmware settings, insert your own public keys and run signed binaries, install OS in virtual environment.